# Crash when starting service with parcelable extra

Tags: android

I'm starting a service using `startForegroundService()` and a Parcelable of type `com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng`. I then get this extra in the `onStartCommand()` method method of my service.

This is working fine when the service is not running, but when the service is already running I get this exception: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Class.isInterface()' on a null object reference" when calling `intent.getParcelableExtra(NAME, LatLng.class)`

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine when I don't specify `LatLng.class` and use the deprecated `Intent.getParcelableExtra(String)` instead of `Intent.getParcelableExtra(String, Class)`